# Javascript - How to sum up all the first and last digit of a number until only two digits are left?

Tags: javascript, numbers, calculation

I am fairly new to programming, just knowing the basics in Javascript and Swift. I am trying to write a simple program which creates, from any entered number, a two digit number by summing up the first and last digit until only two digits are finally left.

Here is an example:

```
num = 1234567:

1+7 = 8
2+6 = 8
3+5 = 8
4 remains

So the first result is: 8884. Now everything is added again:

8+8 = 16
8+4 = 12

The result is 1612. Again everything is summed up:

1+2 = 3
6+1 = 7

The result is 37 - which is also the final result.
```

I am struggling with two things. First the while loop. I was thinking about casting num.toString() and then do a while loop like this in which I change the string to an int again:

```
num.toString()
while (num.length > 2) {
    num = num.parseInt(num, 10);
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't work properly, plus it gets crazy complicated I guess because I would have to switch between string and int each new round, right?

I know how to add all digits together until I get a two digit number (it took me a while to figure this one out) and I am not even sure if this is a good way to do it:

```
var sum = num
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(Number)
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
```

But obviously I cannot use this here and I have no idea how to change the code so that the first and last digit are added together.

Comment: is the second result correct? Shouldn't it be 1216?

Comment: looks like you have a few answers that should fit your needs here. Please mark one as your answer and this issue can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly different approach:

```js
function sum(num) {
  var numString = num.toString();
  var newString = "";
  while (numString.length > 1) { // (1)
    newString += (parseInt(numString[0]) + parseInt(numString[numString.length - 1])).toString(); // (2)
    numString = numString.substring(1, numString.length - 1); // (3)
  }
  newString += numString; // (4)

  if (newString.length > 2) { // (5)
    console.log(newString)
    return sum(newString);
  } else {
    return newString;
  }
}


console.log(sum(1234567));
```

Outputs:

```
8884
1216
73
```

Brief explanation of what's going on:

- (1) Your while loop will process the string until there's either 1 or
  0 characters left
- (2) Add the sum of your first and last character to
  your `newString`
- (3) Remove the first and last characters from your
  `numString` now that they've been saved to the `newString`. Because
  you're overwriting the value in `numString` and shrinking it, this
  will eventually satisfy the while condition of a `numString` with
  less than 2 characters
- (4) Add the remaining characters to
  `newString`, which will either be 1 or 0 characters depending on the
  length of the original number
- (5) if your `newString` is more than 2
  characters, run this method again. Otherwise return your result

Comment: I don't think you understood what OP needs as final result, please read that part: *"from any entered number, a two digit number by summing up the first and last digit until only two digits are finally left."* So, after `8884` it is needed to start the process again, the final result must be 37.

Comment: @all Thanks. Yes I made a mistake. Obviously the original pattern should have been continued. Could someone explain in maybe one or two sentences why this code works? I don't really understand why the while loop can continue? Are the loops stacked inside each other until there is only a two digit number left?

Comment: @PhilSchmitz you call `sum()` on your number. Each time the `numString` passes through the loop, you add the sum of the first and last character to a separate string, you then remove those two characters from `numString`, so that each pass in the while loop, `numString` shrinks until there is 1 character left, which is added at the end of your `newString`. If your `newString` is still more than 2 characters long, you repeat the process

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy. Its just using simple for loop. Its loops upto half of number and add corresponding. The final result according to ur logic should be `73` not `37`

```js
function sum(num){
        //if num is greater than or equal to 2 end the function and return final value
 if(num.length <= 2) return num;
        //converting the num to string beacuse first time input will be number
 num = String(num);
 let result = '';
        //creating a loop upto half of length of the num
 for(let i = 0;i<num.length/2;i++){
                //if the number is not middle one
  if(i !== num.length - 1 - i)
  {
                        //adding the sum of corresponding numbers to result
   result += parseInt(num[i]) + parseInt(num[num.length - 1 - i]);
  }
                //if the number is middle number just add it to result   
                else result += num[i] 
 }
 return sum(result);
}   
console.log(sum(1234567))
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what OP needs as final result, please read that part: *"from any entered number, a two digit number by summing up the first and last digit until only two digits are finally left."* So, after `8884` it is needed to start the process again, the final result must be 37.

Comment: Thanks. I have added a question in another comment above.

Comment: @Phil Schmitz want me add explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested `while` loop and check the string length for the outer loop and the left and right indices for the inner loop

```js
function add(n) {
    var s = n.toString(),
        l, r,
        sum;
    
    while (s.length > 2) {
        l = 0;
        r = s.length - 1;
        sum = [];
        while (l < r) {
            sum.push(+s[l++] + +s[r--]);
        }
        if (l === r) sum.push(s[l]);
        s = sum.join('');
    }
    return +s;
}

console.log(add(1234567));
```

The same but with a recursive function.

```js
function add(n) {
    var s = n.toString(),
        l = 0, r = s.length - 1,
        sum = [];
    
    if (s.length <= 2) return n;
    while (l < r) sum.push(+s[l++] + +s[r--]);
    if (l === r) sum.push(s[l]);
    return add(+sum.join(''));
}

console.log(add(1234567));
```